# Having javascript apply to multiple elements created by php foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, foreach

I have this php foreach loop, which read the videos saved in a folder and load them into my page. 
Under the videos I have created a like and dislike button, which i would like to work with javascript.
The problem is that I cant figure out, how to point js to buttons, when i create unique ID's for the buttons, with a counter in my foreach loop.

My php.

```
$i=1;
foreach($allfiles as $file) {
if($file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != video/ini) // sikre den ikke 
producere . og .. files
{

echo "<div>
        <div>
                        <video width=\"$videoW\" height=\"$videoH\" 
controls>
                          <source src=\"". $dir . $file ."\" type=\"video/mp4\">
                          <source src=\"". $dir . $file ."\" type=\"video/ogg\">
                        </video>
                    </div>



<div><strong> Recorded:</strong> $file </div> </div>";

echo '<img src="/img/like-icon.png" id="like'.$i.'" 
style="width:40px;height:40px;">';
echo '<img src="/img/dislike-icon.png" id="dislike'.$i.'" 
style="width:40px;height:40px;">';
echo '<p style=display:none; id="text'.$i.'">Submitted!</p>';
$i++;
```

My javascript

```
<script type='text/javascript'>  
      for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

        var button = document.getElementById(like[i]);
        var button2 = document.getElementById(dislike[i]);

        button.onclick = function() {
           var text = document.getElementById(text[i]);
           var like = document.getElementById(like[i]);
           var dislike = document.getElementById(dislike[i]);
           if (text.style.display !== 'none') {
              text.style.display = 'none';

           }
           else {
              text.style.display = 'block';
              like.style.display = 'none';
              dislike.style.display = 'none';
        }
     };

        button2.onclick = function() {
           var text = document.getElementById(text[i]);
           var dislike = document.getElementById(dislike[i]);
           var like = document.getElementById(like[i]);

           if (text.style.display !== 'none') {
              text.style.display = 'none';

           }
           else {
             text.style.display = 'block';
             like.style.display = 'none';
             dislike.style.display = 'none';
        }


     };
  };
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('button');`. https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector . You might prefer `document.getElementsByTagName('button');`, or any other way to select html nodes in JavaScript

Comment: A better approach would be to use the same classname on your buttons and assign handlers to your buttons using that class, and then determine which button was clicked within the handlers using `this`, and use “relative” element position to change properties of nearby elements.  You really don’t need unique ids.

Comment: You can give each button a attribute value to group them, such as `data-id='like'` or `data-id='dislike'` then you can use `var likeButtons = document.querySelector('[data-id="like"]');` and loop through them `for (var i = 0; i < likeButtons.length; i++) {
    likeButtons[i].addEventListener('click',liked,false);
}` where `liked` is a reference to a function named `var function liked(){}` etc... containing your current code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very weird... Why are you looping a hundred time to select one element ?

You should look at [querySelector and querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) with which you can select anything using a css selector. For example :

```
document.querySelectorAll('.like');
```

Will return a node list (which you can loop over) containing every element with class="like"

In this case you might want to add an event listener **over each** element. You can imagine something like this :

```
var likes = document.querySelectorAll('.like');

for (var i = 0, length = likes.length; i < length; i++) {
     likes[i].addEventListener('event', myFunction);
}
```

If you don't like querySelectors, you still have some other ways to select multiple elements such as :

- [getElementsByClassName](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)
- [getElementsByTagName](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp)

Also, you shouldn't overwrite style attribute. It's more comfortable to work on project where it is easy to find initial state and changed state. Maybe you should think of a class *hidden* (for example) which would be like this :

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

So if you want to hide them all, you'd juste have to run :

```
var likes = document.querySelectorAll('.like');

for (var i = 0, length = likes.length; i < length; i++) {
     likes[i].classList.add('hidden');
}
```

In case this is resulting of an action :

```
var likes = document.querySelectorAll('.like');

for (var i = 0, length = likes.length; i < length; i++) {
     likes[i].addEventListener('event', myFunction);
}

function myFunction() {
     this.classList.toggle('hidden');
}
```

Comment: Just a side-note on using classes. If your CSS guys are using those classes to style the page, beware they might be also removing them all together at any point. Hence it can be of great benefit to keep style guys use classes while we use custom attributes. The last you want is interdependence where style guys can't style a page because of code might breaking and us not being able to refactor references because of us possibly breaking the style of the page.  Though in the end its neither here or there if you are in control over it all.

Comment: That's totally true and I should have been more specific about this. I think JavaScript has implemented method to have direct access to `data-x` attributes which is safer in order to prevent conflicts between CSS and JS

Answer (score -1):

If I am not wrong,you want like/dislike for perticular video,then try

***onclick*** event on like/dislike image icon .

```
onclick="user_responce(responce,id)"
```

where,

responce:- 1:like,2:dislike

id:- unique video id

In ***user_responce*** function do what you want according to responce.

Hope this work for you.

Comment: If OP is already using event binding through code, suggesting to move in-line would introduce other side effects, making separation of HTML and Script even worse and less maintainable going forward.